# Regex: Select all the words/strings that begins with .dot

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, regex

I want to select with regex all the words that begins with .dot

for example:  `.myself` or `.I go home` or `.5 a clock`

Can you help me?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem with dots is that `.` is the regex character for 'matches anything'. You need to escape it with a backslash.

The following regex would match words that begin with a dot:

```
\.\w+
```

It means that in your example `.I go home` only `.I` will be matched, since the word `go` does not start with a dot. If you would like to change that and extend that to the entire line, so for instance only match the second line in the following text

```
I go home
.I go home
I go home
```

you'd need the following regex:

```
^\..*
```

where `.*` means 'match everything'. (In that case, make sure the Notepad++ option ". matches new line" is disabled, or you'll select the rest of the entire text.)

Comment: @x a: Please don't make wrong modifications. I suggest you to learn basic regex before!